# Operational amplifier question in LTspice

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, amplifier, circuit-design, ltspice

I was asked to pick values for the resistors (I picked R2 = 78 Ω and R1 = 2 Ω) and for Vminus and Vplus.

Can someone please explain what these voltage sources are for and what values I should give them? The circuit for reference (Av = 40 [V/V]):

[image]

Comment: What supply voltage range do you expect will be necessary?

Comment: This circuit is negative feedback in opamp. V+ and V- are saturation value. Go through opamp 741 datasheet and wikipedia to understand how it work and value to give

Comment: im guessing the range spouse to make Vout amplitude 8V because Vin amplitude is 0.2

Comment: It’ll depend on the specific opamp you’re using and how close the input/output signals can get to the supply rails without distortion. If you weren’t told which opamp you’re supposed to use then +15 and -15 are probably a safe bet. That should cover even the worst opamps, like the 741.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a question given as a homework by your professor. I don't want to spoil the fun. The text below is to give you some guidance.

The circuit is a [non-inverting amplifier](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/ap-en/semiconductor/knowledge/e-learning/basics-of-op-amps/chap2/chap2-5.html) and you can adjust its voltage gain \$A_V\$ using this formula

[image]

i.e.,
$$ A_V = 40 = \frac{R1 + R2}{R1}$$
since its gain of 40 is given in the question. Pick a value for, maybe \$R1\$, and solve for \$R2\$. The amplitude of the input sinewave has an amplitude of 0.2V. Since the output voltage gain is 40 (i.e., 40 times the input), so you can find the \$V_{\textrm{plus}}\$ and \$V_{\textrm{minus}}\$ using these formula
$$
\begin{align*}
  V_{\textrm{plus}} &> A_V \times 0.2V \\
  V_{\textrm{minus}} &< -V_{\textrm{plus}}
\end{align*}
$$

Note the amplitudes for \$V_{\textrm{plus}}\$ and \$V_{\textrm{minus}}\$ determine the output voltage range and must be large enough so that the amplified output voltage is within that range.

**Edit**

As pointed out by LvW, please choose reasonable resistance values for \$R1\$ and \$R2\$; preferably in tens or hundreds of kΩ.

Comment: When the resistor values are so low as mentioned in the question (78 resp. 2 Ohms), the opamps finite output resistance must be taken into account.

Comment: Yes you are right, but I kind of missed that out because I figured he was going for a MP111 power op-amp ;-)

Comment: @kaosad Using low resistances for R1 and R2 is simply wasting power. Just because the op-amp can handle that kind of load, doesn't mean R1 and R2 *should* be small. They could be, and there may be reasons to do that (bandwidth, noise and interference considerations for example), but the extremely high input resistance of the op-amp allows you to use much, much larger values for R1 and R2 without any significant degradation in performance. Kilohms or more is typical.

Comment: @Simon Fitch Those values were not chosen by me. They were OP's choice. Of course, I should have pointed that out to OP in my answer, but I didn't.

Comment: @kaosad Really my comment should have been directed at OP, just a general note. My bad. Your answer was clear and comprehensive, +1.